# Expansion in $\epsilon$ in dimensional regularisation

Tags: quantum-field-theory, asymptotics

I am having trouble with a step in a calculation in quantum field theory, as I believe I do not understand the reasoning underlying it.

Often, in the context of dimensional regularisation, we often need an expansion, say,

$$\frac{\Gamma(2-d/2)}{(4\pi)^{d/2}}\left( \frac{1}{\Delta}\right)^{2-d/2} = \frac{2}{\epsilon} - \gamma + \log 4\pi -\log \Delta+ \mathcal{O}(\epsilon)$$

about $\epsilon = 0$ where here $d = 4-\epsilon$. given in QFT texts like Peskin and Schroeder. My issue is this: if we actually expand this term, the actual expansion is,

$$\frac{\Gamma(2-d/2)}{(4\pi)^{d/2}}\left( \frac{1}{\Delta}\right)^{2-d/2} = \frac{1}{16\pi^2} \left[ \frac{2}{\epsilon} - \gamma + \log 4\pi -\log \Delta\right] + \mathcal{O}(\epsilon).$$

They differ by a factor of $\frac{1}{16\pi^2}$, and by inspection it is clear this must be related to the fact that the part of the term that is finite as $d\to 4$, that is, $$\left. \frac{1}{(4\pi)^{d/2}} \right\vert_{d= 4} =\frac{1}{16\pi^2} $$ and they have multiplied by this, but I do not see why this is justified - this factor certainly *is* in the expansion. So, my questions are,

1. Why is it justified to remove the ${16\pi^2}$?
2. Is it true then for any term $f(d) \cdot \Gamma(\dots) \dots$, when we expand for the purposes of computing an amplitude, we can always divide out the expansion by the finite part $\left. f(d)\right\vert_{d=4}$ and eliminate it?

Moreover, if we had say $\left( \frac{1}{\Delta} \right)^{1-d/2}$ instead, would we also at the end divide by $\left. \left( \frac{1}{\Delta} \right)^{1-d/2} \right\vert_{d= 4} = \Delta$?

Comment: Hi. Could you please reference a page on Peskin + Schroeder, for example, where they drop this factor? (I don't see a reason to drop it so maybe the context of the page will help).

Comment: @Rudyard This is the formula given in (A.52) in the appendix, so the fact they give it as a general formula means they must think you can drop it in all cases, at least for the purposes of QFT.

Comment: Thanks. This is a mistake in the book. Here is a list of errata found in Peskin + Schroeder. http://www.ift.uni.wroc.pl/~blaschke/vorles/QFT-err.pdf
As you can see at the end of the document, regarding eq. (A.52), "the right-hand side should be multiplied by an overall factor $1/(4\pi)^2$. Big authors make mistakes too :)

Comment: In general the answer is no: you don't drop such factors when computing amplitudes. (From experience computing).